# How do I read the shortcut path of a printer shortcut linking to a shared printer over UNC with vbs?

Tags: scripting

How do I read the shortcut path of a printer shortcut linking to a shared printer over UNC with vbsripting?

Comment: I think that this is a question for StackOverflow ...

Comment: Other scripting languages are welcome, but vbsript is prefered.

Comment: I was wondering the same, since printer shortcuts is different then all other shortcuts. Although both is .lnk filetype.

If you open a printer shortcut .lnk filetype in notepad, you can parse the file. But one printer shortcut is different to others, so it isnt the same syntax on all printer shortcuts.